# PHPUnit check method returns type

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have a trouble to test what type of content returns the method. On success it returns `string or int`, at fail returns `array`. So code like this

```
public function createAddressBook($bookName)
{
    if (true)
    {
        return 'OK';
    }
    return ['error' => 'FAIL'];
}
```

The real code of the method is API request for new book ID that is `int or string` and i don't know what value will returns. My test code is like so:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->stub = $this->createMock(\My\Class::class);
}

public function tearDown()
{
    $this->stub = null;
}

public function testCreateAddressBook()
{
   $this->stub->method('createAddressBook')->with('TestBookName');
   $result = $this->stub->createAddressBook('TestBookName');
   //what to do now?
}
```

My question is how to test method for returning value type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use is_array(), is_string(), is_int() or gettype() functions or use a !== operator to check if the type and value is different.

is_array($var) checks if the variable is an array.

is_string($var) checks if it is a string.

is_int($var) checks if it is an integer.

gettype($var) returns the type of variable.

Or you can test this with phpUnit functions:

$this->assertIsInt($var);

$this->assertIsArray($var);

$this->assertInternalType('some_datata_type', $var);

Comment: Thanks! Honestly i thought there is exists a PHPUnit way)

Comment: `assertInternalType` is the "phpunit" way (as noted in the answer)